# Firebase data not added to the right child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is as mentioned, the data i added didn't store at the right child. And if data stores at the wrong child, which means the part that check whether child exist won't happen.

```
EditText editTextName;
EditText textDate;
EditText textTime;
Spinner spinnerSport;
ListView listViewTeams;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

//a list to store all the team from firebase database
List<Team> teams;
List<Member> members;

//our database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseTeams;
DatabaseReference databaseMembers;

databaseTeams = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams");
    databaseMembers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("members");


    //getting views
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    spinnerSport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
    listViewTeams = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTeams);
    textDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    textTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textTime);

    //list to store teams
    teams = new ArrayList<>();



    //attaching listener to listview
    listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the selected team
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            checkMember();


            //creating an intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);

            //putting team name and id to intent
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());

            //starting the activity with intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //attaching value event listener
    databaseTeams.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous team list
            teams.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting team
                Team team = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
                //adding team to the list
                teams.add(team);
            }

            //creating adapter
            TeamList teamAdapter = new TeamList(MainActivity.this, teams);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewTeams.setAdapter(teamAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void checkMember(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    final String teamMember = user.getEmail();
    final String encodedEmailAddress = encodeUserEmail(teamMember);
    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(encodedEmailAddress)){
                finish();
            }
            else{
                databaseMembers.push().setValue(encodedEmailAddress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

The email is added into "members" but I want it to be added into whichever the team name the user clicked in the listview, so that the email is store into, let's say "heng" for example. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if there's some lack of information.

Edit 2:
This is my current checkMember,

```
private void checkMember(final String teamName){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final Member memberObject = new Member();

    final String teamMember = user.getEmail();
    final String encodedEmailAddress = encodeUserEmail(teamMember);
    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.child("members").child(teamName).hasChild("teamMember")){
Team team = dataSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
                memberObject.setTeamMember("teamMember");
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put(Team.getTeamName(),memberObject);
              databaseMembers.child(teamName).updateChildren(map);
  databaseMembers.child(teamName).child("teamMember").setValue(encodedEmailAddress);

            }
            else{

            }
        }
```

Member.java

```
public class Member {
private String teamMember;


public Member(){

}

public Member(String teamMember){
    this.teamMember = teamMember;
}

public String getTeamMember() {return teamMember;}
public String setTeamMember(String teamMember) {return this.teamMember;}
}
```

Team.java

```
public class Team {
private String teamId;
private String teamName;
private String teamSport;
private String teamOwner;
private String date;
private String time;

public Team() {

}

public Team(String teamId, String teamName, String teamSport, String teamOwner, String date, String time) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamSport = teamSport;
    this.teamOwner = teamOwner;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTeamId() {return teamId;}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public String getTeamSport() {
    return teamSport;
}

public String getTeamOwner() { return  teamOwner; }

public String getDate(){ return date; }

public String getTime() { return time; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to get the team name from the `ListView` item that was clicked. Having the `team name` you'll be able to use it in a new `DatabaseReference` to add the email address in the exact loaction that you  want. So, let say you have an activity in which you display in a `ListView` using `FirebaseListAdapter` all the teams from your database. This section is named `Teams`.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    DatabaseReference ref = databaseMembers.child("Teams");
    FirebaseListAdapter firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, String.class, R.layout.list) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(final View v, final String teamName, int position) {
            ((TextView )v.findViewById(R.id.team_name)).setText(teamName);
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

After you set the `adapter` we need to `setOnItemClickListener` to see which element from the list, was clicked by the user. We store the element in an intent and after that we'll be able to use it in the second activity.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String teamName = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourNewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("teamName", teamName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In the end, to get `teamName` from the second activity, we to use this code:
`String teamName = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("teamName");`

Hope it helps.

Comment: shoppingListName? This code will add the email into the right child?  I'll add my code where the listview is displayed for you to refer.
Edit: Added my code.

Comment: Sry for that, i edited my answer. It was about `teamName` variable. First of all, you need to display all the `teams` in order to kwnow on which particular team the user has clicked. Once the user has clicked on an item, you'll know which one it was. Having the `teamName`, you be able to use it in the new `Reference` to add the email address as needed. Did you understand what i mean?

Comment: I'll try your code and let you know tomorrow, I think I get what you're saying, sorry I couldn't reply just now, something came up.

Comment: You'll get for sure. Keep me posted.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really still don't understand >.< In my code, I already have the adapter to display my teams which can be seen at the onStart(). Can you use my code as reference? Sorry for all the trouble cause.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, i think you are to leard. So, you are now displaying the teams, that's good. What is the problem now? What to you mean, to use your code as reference?

Comment: Well, I'm using SaravInfern's answer and now I can store the member into the right team the user's select on the listview, however the new member will only replace the old member,so Sarav updated his answer and suggest me to use hash map, which is something I haven't used before. I'm learning how to use it now.

Comment: Yes it's a very good idea. Don't forget when using `Map` to use `updatechildren()` method, in stead of `setValue()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use push() it will always create a new child key in firebase, Try this and let me know if this worked

```
databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.child("members").child("your groupname").hasChild("teamMember")){//do your check for here
                databaseMembers.child("members").child("your groupname").child("teamMember").setValue(encodedEmailAddress);
            }
            else{
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Update1 :**

```
private void checkMember(String teamName){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String teamMember = user.getEmail();
    final String encodedEmailAddress = encodeUserEmail(teamMember);
    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.child("members").child(teamName).hasChild("teamMember")){//do your check for here
                    databaseMembers.child("members").child(teamName).child("teamMember").setValue(encodedEmailAddress);
                }
                else{
                    finish();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

//attaching listener to listview
    listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the selected team
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            checkMember(team.getTeamName());//pass your team name here


            //creating an intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);

            //putting team name and id to intent
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());

            //starting the activity with intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Update2:**

to replace the existing children

```
Member memberObject = new Member();   
memberObject.setTeamMember("your email here");//edit your object

 Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(team.getTeamName(),memberObject);
        firebaseDatabase.getReference().databaseMembers.child("members").child(teamName).updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: your code will create a child "member" under "members", which isn't what i wanted. Also the "your groupname" requires me to put a specific name, again users will click on other names too. I want the email to store into "heng" when user clicks on the heng in the listview for example.

Comment: It should be "members" not "member" i have edited the answer and get the team name from list when user clicks and pass it as child argument

Comment: What about the "your groupname" part? Also I added my code in the question in case you didn't see it.

Comment: I think I almost got it, it really just the "your groupname" part, how to get the team name that the user click into the child?

Comment: Yes thank you, it was able to get the team name, but now it replace the team member with the current email instead of adding it.

Comment: please check my answer I have updated it,  please refer here for clarity https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I'm sorry but where should I put the code? "your email here" is my firebase link?

Comment: I updated my code, I still don't understand how to use hash map though, I couldn't find the proper guide to help me.

Comment: you are creating a team object right is it the container for the teamMember -email??

Comment: all right sorry about that, I should've use the Member object instead of Team. I updated my code again, one more thing I dun understand is the initialize object get(0) part. I ran my code and it crash with this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.

Comment: it was just a sample code!! you must pass the Member object that is to be updated in firebase **`Member memberObject ;` should be initialized with object that is to be updated in firebase**

Comment: I'm completely lost right now, currently inside my Member class there is only one String teamMember, the only thing that is to be updated in firebase here is the teamMember email right? Can you show me how to initialize using my code? Sorry for all these question, I'm just really not that good. >_<

Comment: I added Member and Team class, I believe I've given the necessary code. Again my goal is when user click on the one of the team on listview, then a function will be called to check whether user is member of that team, if he isn't, user's email will be added into that team as one of the team member, if he is then it will proceed to another activity.

Comment: @Zephyros edited my answer please check if this is working for you, You can create a new Member object and set teamMember with your email and pass it to firebase. Hope this must be working for you

Comment: I'm getting non-static method 'getTeamName()' cannot be referenced from a static context on the map.put

Comment: I edited my checkMember(), please help me identify what was wrong.

Comment: `map.put(Team.getTeamName(),memberObject);` use the object of Team instead not the class itself this is why you are getting error I believe. The setter method in your model class should not return a `String` change to `void` instead example: **`public String getTeamMember() {return teamMember;}
public void setTeamMember(String teamMember) {this.teamMember = teamMember;}`**

Comment: So now when I run and click on one of the listview, it crash and the error points to the updatechildren line, so I follow your Update2 and add firebaseDatabase.getReference() into the line, and for some reason android studio cannot resolve the symbol firebaseDatabase.

Comment: i have just posted the sample code for reference dont just copy paste the code as said earlier refer the google dev website for more clarity   -
 firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I manage to run the code but I'm getting this error when listview is clicked 
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Maps with non-string keys are not supported
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildren(Unknown Source)

I will update my code again.